# OpenSSL RSA decrypts only first letter in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am using the following code to decrypt the cipher in C++ using OpenSSL, the problem I am facing is that my code is decrypting only the first letter. **The encrypted string is "VALIDATED" (encrypted in C# using RSACryptoServiceProvider()) but I am getting only "V" in the variable decrypted**. Where I am doing wrong?

```
// real private key
const char privKey[] = R"(-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----)";

// real cipher generated with PublicKey from C# using RSACryptoServiceProvider()
string cipher = "40,229,226,212,224,12,138,61,27,172,149,223,243,132,171,205,80,235,81,41,245,60,187,158,145,243,12,248,101,117,205,188,249,79,85,202,196,131,88,12,202,234,51,74,140,26,162,188,246,2,205,66,174,207,148,236,61,182,193,222,40,241,138,127,150,72,227,45,74,43,176,167,91,81,202,240,30,33,111,41,75,123,222,187,13,181,229,4,206,27,216,176,2,12,13,126,23,192,150,31,120,5,222,91,226,55,178,104,27,85,21,147,3,13,66,39,131,86,157,219,68,5,198,188,85,161,41,119";



std::stringstream test(cipher);
    std::string segment;
    std::vector<std::string> seglist;



    while (std::getline(test, segment, ','))
    {
        seglist.push_back(segment);
    }

    int cipherSegSize = seglist.size();
    unsigned char* cipherByteArray = (unsigned char*)malloc(cipherSegSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < cipherSegSize; i++) {
        int tempInt = std::stoi(seglist[i]);
        cipherByteArray[i] = tempInt;
    }

    char* decrypted = NULL;

    BIO* mem2 = BIO_new_mem_buf(privKey, -1);

    RSA* private_key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(mem2, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    BIO_free(mem2);

    decrypted = (char*)malloc(cipherSegSize);
    int cipherSize = RSA_size(private_key);
    int decrypt_length = private_decrypt(cipherSize, cipherByteArray, (unsigned char*)decrypted, private_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    if (decrypt_length == -1) {
        LOG("An error occurred in private_decrypt() method");
    }

    cout << decrypted << endl;
```

Comment: Dunno what you think this does: ` cipherByteArray[cipherSegSize] = NULL;` But really not what you think. If you're trying to NUL-terminate a string, you must allocate enough bytes, _i.e._ `cipherSegSize + 1`. Also, `NULL` is not the correct value to set. It'll work, but it's bad form. Use either `0` or `'\0'`. While fixing these may not fix your problem, who knows. Currently you have undefined behavior, so anything goes.

Comment: Ignore this line, I have removed it. It was just added while debugging it's not there now.

Comment: You're supposed to pass in the size of the encrypted message (`cipherSegSize`), instead you pass in `cipherSize`, which is the "RSA modulus size in bytes".

Comment: Unrelated: please do away with this `malloc` and `free` nonsense. An `std::string` can hold arbitrary bytes, as can a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: I got it working using the following project (https://github.com/iwpz/Cpp-RSA-AES-with-Csharp) using Crypto++ library. I have to change my C# project too due to the different techniques used in the GitHub project. Thank you so much everyone.